# How to pass a class to a function generation an expression

Tags: c#, expression

I call a function with

```
uniqueItems = _distinctDao.GetProjectsFromDb(c.colName);
```

and the function is

```
    public List<string> GetProjectsFromDb(string columnName)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Project), "x");

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, columnName), parameter);
        Expression<Func<Project, string>> funcExpression = (Expression<Func<Project, string>>) lambda;

        using (var mLEntities = new myLab02Entities1())
        {
            var cl = mLEntities.Projects.AsQueryable().Select(funcExpression).Distinct(); 

            List<string> searchRes = cl.AsEnumerable().ToList();

            return searchRes;
        }
    }
```

This works as expected, but I need to query several databases as `Project`s in the example as `Person`s, `Product`s etc., thus I want one function that can be called for different databases.

I know that I can pass `typeof(Project)` in the function call to replace `Project` in the `ParameterExpression`, but how can I pass the class (`Project`) for `Expression<Func<Project, string>>`?

Comment: The expression is easy enough, as you can just make the method generic, but that fact you directly reference it in `mLEntities.Projects` will be more problematic.

Comment: Please clarify the use of the term “database” — do you mean a table and/or entity? What's the declaration of `myLab02Entities1` and how is it related to `Project`, `Person` etc. classes?

Comment: I use a SQL database with tables like Project, Person, etc, and EntityFramework 6.1.3. “myLab02Entities1” comes from the connection string. In my post “databases” is incorrect; in fact it meant entities from the edmx. Hucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `myLab02Entities1` has all the properties that you want to query (`Projects`, `Persons`, `Products` etc), you can do this:

```
public List<string> GetObjectsFromDb<T>(string columnName, Func<myLab02Entities1, IEnumerable<T>> entitySelector)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, columnName), parameter);
    Expression<Func<T, string>> funcExpression = (Expression<Func<T, string>>) lambda;

    using (var mLEntities = new myLab02Entities1())
    {
        var cl = entitySelector(mLEntities).AsQueryable().Select(funcExpression).Distinct(); 

        List<string> searchRes = cl.AsEnumerable().ToList();

        return searchRes;
    }
}
```

I basically added a generic parameter `T` and a new parameter called `entitySelector` that returns the corresponding property in `myLab02Entities1`. You can apply a stricter generic constraint on `T` if you want.

Usage:

```
GetObjectsFromDb("someColumn", x => x.Projects);
GetObjectsFromDb("someColumn", x => x.Persons);
GetObjectsFromDb("someColumn", x => x.Products);
```

Comment: For a test, I put the GetObjectsFromDb function and the method call in a class ChemDistinctDao in namespace myLabDAL. When running, I get a rather long error message: 
The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<myLabDal.Project>' must be convertible to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.DbSet<myLabDal.Project>> in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic method 'List<string> myLabDal.ChemDistinctDao.GetItemsFromDb<T> (string, Func<myLab02Entities1,T>). What might be the reason for this?

Comment: thank you for your reply. Your solution now works perfectly.

Comment: Sweeper: I did not want to unaccept your answer. I don't know what I did do remove the mark. Hope it is accepted now. Hucky